# how can i create a random array of floats from 0 to 1

Tags: python, list, random

I want to create a random float array of size 100, with the values in the array ranging from 0 to 1.
I have tried `random.sample(range(1),100)` but that does not work.
How can i get what i want to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[random.random() for _ in range(100)]
```

Comment: +1 : I didn't know about the conventional use of `_` for throwaway variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you will be doing a lot of array computations, consider using the numpy library (http://www.numpy.org/).  With numpy, you can use the function `numpy.random.random`:

```
>>> a = numpy.random.random(100)
```